# In Power Automate flow, how to Get Items from SharePoint List that were created yesterday?

Tags: power-automate, sharepoint-list

**Desired Behaviour**

I'm wanting to run a recurrent flow daily, that gets items from a SharePoint List:

- That have the status of `Submitted`
- That were created yesterday

**What I've Tried**

Initially, I tried to add this to the `Filter query` in the `Get items` action:

```
Status eq 'Submitted' and Created eq '@{addDays(utcNow(),-1,'yyyy-MM-dd')}'
```

It doesn't return any results, probably because the `Created` column value is something like:

```
2023-08-17T05:07:46Z
```

Whereas, the output of the `addDays()` expression is something like:

```
2023-08-17
```

Of course I've googled for phrases like:

> power automate sharepoint list get items created yesterday

And it returns results like those below:

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Flow-to-Get-SharePoint-Items-created-yesterday/td-p/802949

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Filter-SharePoint-list-to-only-include-items-created-yesterday/td-p/758918

Strangely, the accepted answers are:

```
Created gt '@{addDays(utcNow(),-1,'yyyy-MM-dd')}'

Created ge '@{addDays(utcNow('yyyy-MM-dd'),-1,'yyyy-MM-dd')}'
```

Neither of these make sense to me, because they are both saying:

- Get entries that were Created after 24 hours ago

In both of these cases, that would also return entries from today as well (I only want entries that were created yesterday).

**Question**

What filter query do I need to use in the `Get Items` action that equates to:

- Get all items that were created yesterday

**For Reference**

I've created a bunch of time-related `Compose` actions in the process of troubleshooting the issue.

They are pasted below for reference in case they help in figuring out a solution.

Compose - Example Created value:

```
2023-08-17T05:07:46Z
```

Compose - UTC now converted to Brisbane timezone:

```
@{convertTimeZone(utcNow(),'UTC','E. Australia Standard Time')}
```

Compose - UTC now converted to Brisbane timezone formatted:

```
@{formatDateTime(convertTimeZone(utcNow(), 'UTC', 'E. Australia Standard Time'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')}
```

Compose - UTC yesterday converted to Brisbane timezone formatted:

```
@{formatDateTime(convertTimeZone(addDays(utcNow(), -1), 'UTC', 'E. Australia Standard Time'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using filter query in get items action like below:

```
Status eq 'Submitted' and Created ge datetime'@{concat(addDays(utcNow(),-1,'yyyy-MM-dd'),'T00:00:00Z')}' and Created lt datetime'@{concat(formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyy-MM-dd'),'T00:00:00Z')}'
```

Where Status and Created are the internal names of your SharePoint list columns. You can get the internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

**Reference**: [Filter Created in SP REST API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/255543/filter-created-in-sp-rest-api/255555#255555)

Comment: I think this is right, so should be accepted. If u can add the following logic to make answer even more helpful it would be appreciated. How to get everything that was created YESTERDAY in Brisbane, Australia timezone?  This is one attempt I have tried that seems to work:  `Status eq 'Submitted' and Created ge datetime'@{concat(addHours(addDays(utcNow(),-1), -10, 'yyyy-MM-dd'),'T00:00:00Z')}' and Created lt datetime'@{concat(addHours(utcNow(), 10, 'yyyy-MM-dd'),'T00:00:00Z')}'`

Comment: Here is an explanation of my attempt above:  I wrap your reference to YESTERDAY in UTC time in `addHours()` and minus 10 hours (the Brisbane timezone offset), and wrap your  reference to NOW in UTC time in `addHours()` and add 10 hours (the Brisbane timezone offset).   It still hurts my brain trying to understand what I am doing here, but it seems to work.

Comment: So the logic to get everything from yesterday in local timezone is:  Get everything greater than or equal to 12:00am on the day associated with 10 hours before yesterday in UTC time, and less than 12:00am on the day associated with now plus 10 hours in UTC time.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Update, what I suggested above is not working as desired - it is returning some results from 2 days ago, i.e when running it at 9:35am on 23/08/23, it is returning an entry with a Created date of 21/08/23 at 3:17pm.  It should only be returning entries from 22/08/23.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost done with this formula:

```
Status eq 'Submitted' and Created eq '@{addDays(utcNow(),-1,'yyyy-MM-dd')}'
```

Except the last part with the formatting is not needed!

Also, you have to get items before today (`lower than`), but after day -2 (`greater than`).

Try this:

```
Status eq 'Submitted' and Created gt '@{addDays(utcNow(),-2)}' and Created lt '@{utcNow()}'
```

I have a flow to get items older than a week (7 days), and my formula (`filter query` in a `get items` SharePoint action) is:

```
Created lt '@{addDays(utcNow(),-7)}'
```